# Screw with somebody

Tags: phrasal-verbs, word-meaning

In a forum thread, someone posted a video of a guy throwing a racoon down the stairs because the racoon was fighting with his dog.

A forum user commented:

> I bet that Raccoon never screws with the dog again. :Rofl:

Does *screw* here means annoy/harass?

Comment: *Screw **with*** may mean annoy or harass, as here, or manipulate, involve oneself with, tinker with; *screw* by itself has a range of meanings.

Comment: Yeah, if you're learning the language, you want to be careful here. To "screw with" someone is to deliberately confuse them. To "screw" someone is a slightly vulgar way of saying to have sex. Like most vulgar English terms for sexual relations, it can also mean to deliberately cause someone serious problems. (Which seems to reflect a rather negative view of sex, but whatever.) Note that even when used in the sense of "causing him trouble", it is considered vulgar and should not be used in formal situations or with people who might be offended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. To "screw with" someone is to deliberately attempt to confuse, annoy, or provoke them.